# How to debug a EMVideoView that is not loading a video in Android?

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, playback

Anyone knows why this Video View code not loading the Video on clicking? I have a layout with videoview (`EMVideoView`) that have a listview (View List from `VideoSelectionListAdapter`).

The list load where i wanted but on click or pressing it doesn't play video or even try to load. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong please?

Here is my new code after edited with Elefas answer.

```
public class VideoPlayerActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {
public static final String EXTRA_INDEX = "EXTRA_INDEX";
public static final int PLAYLIST_ID = 6; //Arbitrary, for the example (different from audio)

protected EMVideoView emVideoView;
protected PlaylistManager playlistManager;

protected int selectedIndex;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
    emVideoView = (EMVideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_play_activity_video_view);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_selection_activity);
    ListView exampleList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.selection_activity_list);
    exampleList.setAdapter(new VideoSelectionListAdapter(this));
    exampleList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    emVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    setupPlaylistManager();
    playlistManager.setVideoView(emVideoView);
    playlistManager.play(0, false);

}

private void setupPlaylistManager() {
    playlistManager = new PlaylistManager();

    List<MediaItem> mediaItems = new LinkedList<>();
    for (VideoItems.VideoItem item : VideoItems.getItems()) {
        MediaItem mediaItem = new MediaItem(item);
        mediaItems.add(mediaItem);
    }

    playlistManager.setAllowedMediaType(EMPlaylistManager.MediaType.AUDIO_AND_VIDEO);
    playlistManager.setParameters(mediaItems, selectedIndex);
    playlistManager.setPlaylistId(PLAYLIST_ID);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    emVideoView.start();
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    //Starts the video playback as soon as it is ready
    emVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(this);  //it's the actual code inside init()
    emVideoView.start();
}

}
```

Comment: What was supposed to happen and what actually happened?

Comment: woow shark very quick reply thanks but as I already stated, I would love the video to play.

Comment: Have you even seen how it works? You should see the official demo project. too much things look missing in your code. You don't have any `PlayListManager`. How would it know which video to play unless you tell it to. https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/com/devbrackets/android/exomediademo/ui/activity/VideoPlayerActivity.java

Comment: Yes I went to Githab and even download from there.

Comment: Yes I went to Githab and even download from there. But i tested the simple code that dont have playlist and it worked, but when I try to use my code, trying to making the video play on the same activity it doesnt, so it only work if you click on the original playlist that comes with the source, which will open new activity (VideoPlayerActivity) FullscreenActivity, (but what I want is to load the video on the same videoview with the layout that I made.

Comment: Basically what I am trying to say is I would love the video to load from my layout and not the demo layout. so I tried to change it to my layout but failed.Can some one please look at it and tell me me whats missing please?

Answer (score 1):

Well what I suppose is that you dont follow exactly the recommended way of the `ExoMedia` (https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia) code you are using.

It would be better if you setup your view inside onCreate
so remove

```
emVideoView = (EMVideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_play_activity_video_view);
```

from `onItemClick` and put it in `onCreate`

Then you have defined an `init()` method but it is not called anywhere. Better call it after initializing your `emVideoView`. e.g.

```
emVideoView = (EMVideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_play_activity_video_view);
emVideoView = (EMVideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_play_activity_video_view);
emVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(this);
setupPlaylistManager();
playlistManager.setVideoView(emVideoView);
playlistManager.play(0, false);
```

and define the `setupPlaylistManager` method somewhere in your class

```
private void setupPlaylistManager() {
    playlistManager = new PlaylistManager();

    List<MediaItem> mediaItems = new LinkedList<>();
    for (VideoItems.VideoItem item : VideoItems.getItems()) {
        MediaItem mediaItem = new MediaItem(item);
        mediaItems.add(mediaItem);
    }

    playlistManager.setAllowedMediaType(EMPlaylistManager.MediaType.AUDIO_AND_VIDEO);
    playlistManager.setParameters(mediaItems, selectedIndex);
    playlistManager.setPlaylistId(PLAYLIST_ID);
}
```

This will eventually call the `onPrepared` callback and play the video you want.

Comment: Hi ElefasGR Thanks for your reply but still not playing. As I might forgot to mention that I am a total NOOB on making android apps (especially VideoView) and I have Zero knowledge of coding with Java, so guys be easy please, can you see my code and tell me where i am doing wrong please?. Many thanks

Comment: Note I have removed the init since it never worked. ( grayed out).  is this why?